# How to send packets from stm32f4, 192.x.x.x to 10.x.x.x with lwip

Tags: c, stm32f4, lwip

I`m attempting to force an out-of-gateway address using the udp_sendto () function. 
ex) listen IP address : 192.168.1.10 -> send IP address : 224.0.0.1

This concept takes a packet to a unicast address 
and sends it to a multicast address.

when i try udp_sendto(224.0.0.1), it`s pending in ip4.c: ip4_route() line 164.

I want inspiration how to fix it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Try to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438577/implementing-lwip-multicast-on-stm32f7-freertos

Comment: simply Two options were changed. lwip_multicast_tx_options & lwip_igmp
and Try your link.
It was possible to send to a multicast address without joining the igmp group.
Thank you.